# Is it possible to change a PID in Supervisord

Tags: nginx, supervisord

I have a /bin/NginxWrapper script that runs NGINX:

```
#!/bin/env sh

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ENVIRONMENT_ROOT/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/bin/nginx
```

Supervisord config command points the above script, so that when we kick off Nginx, supervisor will first call this script

```
[program:nginx]
command=/bin/NginxWrapper -c /nginx/nginx.conf -g "daemon off;"
```

The problem is, Superisord is now storing the PID of this script, instead of the PID of Nginx. And if i try to send HUP to Nginx, its unable to.

Is it possible to change the PID in supervisord so that it's Nginx's PID?
OR
Is there a way to chain Supersivord command so that i dont need the wrapper, and can just chain something like

```
[program:nginx]
    command= export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ENVIRONMENT_ROOT/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && /bin/NginxWrapper -c /nginx/nginx.conf -g "daemon off;"
```

Many thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```perl
/bin/nginx
```

to

```perl
exec /bin/nginx
```